# Android data binding Two-way binding cannot resolve a setter for boolean property

Tags: android, data-binding

I am trying to dynamically set and change a background drawable based on a boolean defined on my `BaseObservable` class below but I get an error saying it can't do two-way data binding on "isFollowing" method.

error is this:

> The expression 'viewModel.isFollowing()' cannot be inverted, so it
> cannot be used in a two-way binding Details: Two-way binding cannot
> resolve a setter for boolean property 'isFollowing'

```
 private var isFollowing: Boolean = false

 @Bindable
 fun isFollowing(): Boolean {
      return isFollowing
 }
    
 @BindingAdapter("android:background")
 fun setIsFollowing(frameLayout: FrameLayout, isFollowing: Boolean) {

      if (this.isFollowing != isFollowing) {

           this.isFollowing = isFollowing
           if(this.isFollowing){
               frameLayout.background = frameLayout.context.getDrawable(R.drawable.following)
           }else{
               frameLayout.background = frameLayout.context.getDrawable(R.drawable.follow)
            }          
      }
  }
```

Here is my layout file

```
  <FrameLayout
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="@={viewModel.isFollowing}"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
```

I tried this as suggested but no joy:

```
 companion object {

     private var isFollow: Boolean = false

     @JvmStatic
     val isFollowing: Boolean
     @Bindable get() = isFollow

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change method to getter:

```
val isFollowing: Boolean
    @Bindable get() = _isFollowing
```

Comment: Hi i sitill get the same error and converted isFollowing to

    @get:Bindable
    val isFollowing : Boolean
    get() = this.isFollow

Comment: I edited my post, unfortunately i can't try it on my computer right now.

Comment: where does _isFollowing come from?

Comment: I renamed isFollowing from your example to _isFollowing, and use isFollowing for property name.

Comment: OK  i tried the above and still get similar error:

The expression 'com.catwalkcouture.theeditor.ui.home.model.HomeFeedTopLookViewModel.isFollowing()' cannot be inverted, so it cannot be used in a two-way binding

Details: Two-way binding cannot resolve a setter for boolean property 'isFollowing' 

i even wrapped it insde a compaion object and added @JvmStatic